# How to show a multiple line Display impl via the format! macro?

Tags: rust

I have the following Display impl for a Vec struct:

```
impl fmt::Display for Response {
// This trait requires `fmt` with this exact signature.
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    // Write strictly the first element into the supplied output
    // stream: `f`. Returns `fmt::Result` which indicates whether the
    // operation succeeded or failed. Note that `write!` uses syntax which
    // is very similar to `println!`.
    if &self.data.transactions.len() <= &0 {
        write!(f, "No transactions today")?;
    }

    for t in &self.data.transactions {
        writeln!(f, "{:.2} USD {}. Taken from {}. Account: {}", t.amount, t.memo, t.category_name, t.account_name)?;
    }
    
    Ok(())
}
```

I want to pass this like the following to a `format!` where I generate a HTML E-Mail body:

`format!("<html><body><h2>Transactions</h2>{}</body></html>", response)`

However, the `writeln!` macro doesn't produce multiple lines in the generated `String`. When I print it out to `stdout`, it works fine.

> Is there an option to do this somehow with `format!` as well?

Comment: This is not related to Rust. In HTML `\n` (generated by `writeln!` here) has no more effect than a regular space. You have to explicitly insert `<br>` tags in order to break lines or use `<p>` tags for your paragraphs. You could also insert the text between `<pre>` and `</pre>` for a typewriter style conforming exactly to your manual formatting.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since at a specific location in your code you decide to explicitly generate HTML tags (`<html><body>...</html>`), maybe a reasonable solution would be to keep the text formatting (for the console) as you already did, but in this specific case (HTML) [replace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.replace) all the `\n` by `<br>`.

```
    let txt = format!("{}", response);
    println!("~~~~ console ~~~~");
    println!("{}", txt);
    println!("~~~~ html ~~~~");
    let html = format!(
        "<html><body><h2>Transactions</h2>{}</body></html>",
        txt.replace("\n", "<br>")
    );
    println!("{}", html);
```